# How to update Angular scope properties when they are passed into directives?

Tags: angularjs

I have functionality where developers can add custom Angular views where they can bind properties to the $scope.settings object. When clicking on the save button the $scope.settings object will be converted to JSON and saved to the database. Something like this will be the result:

```
{
    "name": "bob",
    "age": "25"
}
```

As long as I add elements like `<input type="text" ng-model="settings.name" />` everything goes as expected.

But, now I want to add directives like this:

```
<umb-property property="property in properties">
    <umb-editor model="property"></umb-editor>
</umb-property>
```

With the following code:

```
$scope.properties = [
    {
        label: 'Name',
        alias: 'name',
        view: 'textbox',
        value: $scope.settings.name
    },
    {
        label: 'Age',
        alias: 'age',
        view: 'number',
        value: $scope.settings.age
    }
];
```

The 'editor' directive loads views in place based on the 'view' property. The views are third party. The editors are loaded in a dialog. After submission of the settings dialog, the following line of code will convert the settings to JSON:

```
$scope.dialog = {
     submit: function (model) {
         var settingsJson = JSON.stringify(model.settings);
     },
     close: function (oldModel) {
         //
     }
 };
```

In this case I cannot parse the $scope.settings to JSON, because the $scope.settings.name is not updated anymore. The $scope.editorModel.value was updated instead.

How can I bind the $scope.editorModel.value to $scope.settings.name?
I don't want to end up with a solution where I must update all $scope.settings values with the corresponding values from the editor models, because I want to support the dynamic way to convert the $scope.settings to a JSON value in the database.

Comment: can you show a more complete example of the code you have?  the way you are describing what you *want* to accomplish, you would have more than one `editorModel` object, one for each instance of `editor`.  what you are showing here, however, is trying to use a singular `editorModel` for multiple instances, which isn't really going to work.

Comment: I think it can be the way you are doing your directive, Can you put the complete directive code please? Tnx

Comment: I provided my question with more concrete examples.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly but from code I can only tell you that values in `$scope.properties` will be updated (with `value`) but not `$scope.settings.name` because it is not passed to directive.

Comment: Exactly, but I want to send back a clean object with the settins values only. The properties object contains other info like view and label and would not result into the JSON structure I want to have as explained in the question, so I want to map the values in the propeties object back to my settings object in a manner that i dont need to specify each mapping for the properties.

Comment: For example I dont want to do: $scope.settings.name = $scope.properties[0].value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example I dont want to do: `$scope.settings.name = $scope.properties[0].value`

Use [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```
for (var i=0; i<$scope.properties.length; i++) {
    $scope.settings[$scope.properties[i].alias] = $scope.properties[i].value;
};
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="prop in properties">
    <input ng-model="prop.value">
</div>
```